# An elegant, readable way to read Butcher tableau from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to read a specifically formatted file (namely, the Butcher tableau) in python 3.5.
The file looks like this(tab separated):

```
S
a1  b11  b12  ... b1S
a2  b21  b22  ... b2S
...
aS  bS1  bS2  ... bSS
0.0 c1   c2   ... cS
[tolerance]
```

for example, (tab separated)

```
2
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 0.5 0.5
0.0 0.5 0.5
0.0001
```

So my code looks like i'm writing in C. Is there a more pythonic approach to parsing this file? Maybe there are numpy methods that could be used here?

```
#the data from .dat file
S = 0    #method order, first char in .dat file
a = []   #S-dim left column of buther tableau
b = []   #S-dim matrix
c = []   #S-dim lower row
tolerance = 0 # for implicit methods

def parse_method(file_name):
    'read the file_name, process lines, produce a Method object'
    try:
        with open('methods\\' + file_name) as file:
            global S
            S = int(next(file))
            temp = []
            for line in file:
                temp.append([float(x) for x in line.replace('\n', '').split('\t')])
        for i in range(S):
            a.append(temp[i].pop(0))
            b.append(temp[i])
        global c
        c = temp[S][1:]
        global tolerance
        tolerance = temp[-1][0] if len(temp)>S+1 else 0
    except OSError as ioerror:
        print('File Error: ' + str(ioerror))
```

Comment: Can you describe the actual file with real values? It will be easier to understand.

Comment: you're right, I've added an example

Comment: Ok. I'll add an answer.

Comment: separating the parsing from the object creation would probably make the code easier to understand (and make it possible to provide useful feedback on parsing errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def read_butcher(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
        S = int(fh.readline())
        array = np.fromfile(fh, float, (S+1)**2, '\t')
        rest = fh.read().strip()

    array.shape = (S+1, S+1)
    a = array[:-1,  0]
    b = array[:-1, 1:]
    c = array[ -1, 1:]
    tolerance = float(rest) if rest else 0.0

    return a, b, c, tolerance
```

Although I'm not entirely sure how consistently `numpy.fromfile` advances the file pointer... There are no guarantees in the documentation.

Handling of file exceptions should probably be done outside of the parsing method.

Comment: actually, this one is more concise and kind of more readable, so I'll vote it as an answer. The only thing though is the 4th argument in `numpy.fromfile()` - it should be just `'\t'`, without `b`, otherwise it throws an exception

Comment: @Nick - I tried to be clever there, I guess just `'\t'` should work on both python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Code -

```
from collections import namedtuple


def parse_file(file_name):
    with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
        file_content = f.readlines()
    file_content = [line.strip('\n') for line in file_content]
    s = int(file_content[0])
    a = [float(file_content[i].split()[0]) for i in range(1, s + 1)]
    b = [list(map(float, file_content[i].split()[1:]))
         for i in range(1, s + 1)]
    c = list(map(float, file_content[-2].split()))
    tolerance = float(file_content[-1])
    ButcherTableau = namedtuple('ButcherTableau', 's a b c tolerance')
    bt = ButcherTableau(s, a, b, c, tolerance)
    return bt

p = parse_file('a.txt')

print('S :', p.s)
print('a :', p.a)
print('b :', p.b)
print('c :', p.c)
print('tolerance :', p.tolerance)
```

Output -

```
S : 2
a : [0.0, 1.0]
b : [[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5]]
c : [0.0, 0.5, 0.5]
tolerance : 0.0001
```

Comment: Thank you, that works and is indeed more pythonic. My only concern is the usage of `map` which I heard is discouraged. But here it seems more appropriate than list comprehensions

Comment: Maps are absolutely alright when you want to apply the same function to a list. Different people have different preferences though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bunch of suggestions you should consider:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv

def parse_method(file_name):
    # for conveniency create a namedtuple
    bt = namedtuple('ButcherTableau', dict(a=[], b=[], c=[], order=0, tolerance=0))

    line = None

    # advice ①: do not assume file path in a function, make assumptions as close to your main function as possible (to make it easier to parameterize later on)
    # advice ②: do not call your file "file" so you're not shadowing the class "file" that's loaded globally at runtime
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        # read the first line alone to setup your "method order" value before reading all the tab separated values
        bt.order = int(f.readline())

        # create a csv reader with cell separator as tabs
        # and create an enumerator to have indexes for each line
        for idx, line in enumerate(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')))

            # instead of iterating again, you can just check the index
            # and build your a and b values
            if idx < bt.order:
               bt.a.append(line.pop(0))
               bt.b.append(line)

        # if line is None (as set before the for), it means we did not iterate, meaning that we need to make it an error
        if not line:
            raise Exception("File is empty. Could not parse {}".format(file_name))

        # finally you can build your c (and tolerance) values with the last line, which conveniently is still available once the for is finished
        bt.c = line[1:]
        bt.tolerance = line[0] if idx > S+1 else 0

    # avoid the globals, return the namedtuple instead and use the results in the caller function
    return bt
```

This code is untested (just rework of your code as I read it), so it might not work as is, but you might want take the good ideas and make them your own.